# Named bulk registration with windsor castle

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, castle-windsor-3

In my project I have the interface *IProcess* and a lot of classes implementing this interface. I need to register all those implementations. The following code is working fine for me:

```
Container.Register(Component.For<IProcess>().Named("SampleProcess").ImplementedBy<SampleProcess>());
Container.Register(Component.For<IProcess>().Named("SampleProcess2").ImplementedBy<SampleProcess2>());
```

However using this approach for registering is tedious if I have a lot of implementations. Therefore I am looking for a registration method to register all implementations of IProcess in a given assembly **by name**. The name that should be used for the registration key is just the class name.

Can someone pls give me a hint where to look for?

Comment: Isn't that what happens by default if you don't specify a name explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a classic scenario for the [convention registration API](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md#registering-components-by-conventions).

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromThisAssembly()
        .BasedOn<IProcess>()
        .WithServiceBase()
        // and then if you *really* need to explicitly control naming
        .Configure(c => c.Named(c.Implementation.Name)
        )
```

Generally explicitly naming your components shouldn't be used, unless you have multiple components with the same implementation class, so just make sure you *really* need it.

Comment: Thank you Krzysztof! It was really this simple - I was playing around alot with the convention reg api but something was always missing. The line containing the name configuration was indeed not needed in my case.